# Why and how to fix this error message using Ada?

Tags: ada

```
with Ada.Text_IO ; use Ada.Text_IO ;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO ; use Ada.Float_Text_IO ;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO ; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO ;

procedure Main is

begin

   declare
      V_PRODUCT := Float;
      V_RETURN := Float;
      V_PAID := Floar;
      
      type V_COIN is delta 0.01 digist 8;
      type INDEX is range 1 ..8;
      
      type MY_RANGE_COIN is array (INDEX) of V_COIN;
      Arr: MY_RANGE_COIN := (0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0);
      
      
      --T_COINS
      
   begin
      Put_Line ("Introducir precio del prodcuto. ");
      Get (V_PRODUCT);
      
      Put_Line ("Introducir cuantia");
      Get (V_PAID);
      
      Put_Line ("La cantidad a devolver es : " & V_RETURN);
  
   end;
   
   function V_RETURN;
   declare
      REFUND : Float := 0.0;
   begin
      REFUND := V_PAID - V_PRODUCT;
      return REFUND ;
   end;
   
   
   null;
end Main;
```

That is the error.
[image]

I'm trying to make a machine that returns the return of a purchase.

```
V_PRODUCT --> Value_PRODUCT
V_RETURN --> Value_RETURN
V_PAID --> Value_PAID
```

All of this -->

```
type V_COIN is delta 0.01 digist 8;
      type INDEX is range 1 ..8;
      type MY_RANGE_COIN is array (INDEX) of V_COIN;
      Arr: MY_RANGE_COIN := (0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0);
```

Its for made array with all Euro coin value.

Funtion it's just for know how many need to return.

Comment: Please, [no images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/230513).

Comment: Going forward, you can accept an answer by clicking on the [empty check mark](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/163188) at the left.

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest you look at the online course [here](https://learn.adacore.com).

That said,

- you can declare things between the `procedure Main is` and the `begin`
- you really don’t need a function to subtract the price from the amount paid (but if you did, declare it in the same place as above)
- you have to be careful mixing text and float output

so it could look like this (omitting the stuff about coins for the moment):

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO ; use Ada.Text_IO ;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO ; use Ada.Float_Text_IO ;

procedure Main is

   V_PRODUCT : Float;
   V_RETURN : Float;
   V_PAID : Float;

begin
   Put_Line ("Introducir precio del prodcuto. ");
   Get (V_PRODUCT);

   Put_Line ("Introducir cuantia");
   Get (V_PAID);

   V_RETURN := V_PAID - V_PRODUCT;

   Put ("La cantidad a devolver es : ");
   Put (V_RETURN);
   New_Line;
end Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed these lines:

```
V_PRODUCT := Float;
V_RETURN := Float;
V_PAID := Floar;
_____________________
V_PRODUCT : Float;
V_RETURN : Float;
V_PAID : Float;
```

Comment: See also [_Ada Reference Manual: 3.3.1 Object Declarations_](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-3-1.html).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).